# Does this way of finding longest common substring solution fall into dynamic programming?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have started learning the Dynamic Programming, in that way I have written a program to find and written longest common substring of two given strings and it is executing fine, after that I went on to google and search for the same, but everyone is using matrix or (double dimension array) to store the subproblem solutions. But I have used only single dimension and I believe, time complexity of my solution is O(n*m). I just want to confirm that my solution is really dynamic programming or not.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class LongestCommonSubstring {
    private class LCSUtility {
        int lengthOfLCS;
        ArrayList<String> lcsList;
        LCSUtility() {
            lcsList = new ArrayList<>();
            lengthOfLCS=0;
        }
    }
    public LCSUtility findLongestCommonSubstring(String str1,String str2) {
      int[] lcs = new int[str1.length()];
      LCSUtility lcsUtility= new LCSUtility();
      /* Filling out the 1-D array with 1 if that character from "first string is existed in "second string" otherwise 0"*/  
      for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
          if(str2.contains(str1.substring(i,i))) {
              lcs[i] =1;
          } else {
              lcs[i] =0;
          }
        }
        /* Finding the sub strings of "first string" are part of "second string" and storing results into 1-D array*/
        for(int i=1;i<str1.length();i++){
            String sub = str1.substring(i-1,i+1);
            if(str2.contains(sub)) {
                lcs[i] = 1+lcs[i-1];
            }
        }
        /* Finding Max of the LCSs*/
        for(int i=0;i<lcs.length;i++){
            System.out.print(" " + lcs[i]);
            if(lcs[i]>lcsUtility.lengthOfLCS) {
                lcsUtility.lengthOfLCS=lcs[i];
            }
        }
        /* Adding out all lcs to the utility object's list*/
        for(int i=0;i<lcs.length;i++) {
            if(lcs[i] == lcsUtility.lengthOfLCS) {
                lcsUtility.lcsList.add(str1.substring(i-lcsUtility.lengthOfLCS+1,i+1));
            }
        }
        return lcsUtility;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        LCSUtility lcsUtility = new LongestCommonSubstring().findLongestCommonSubstring("tutorialhorizon", "dynamictutorialProgramming hellow");
        System.out.print(" ******* Longest Common Sub of Given Strings are  \n");
        for(String s: lcsUtility.lcsList) {
            System.out.print(" " +s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @Chris Thanks for your suggestion, I will give a try.